# Why should I create a separate schema for security objects in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, row-level-security

I do want to use the row-level security feature of SQL Server 2016. In the best practice part of the documentation it says:

> It is highly recommended to create a separate schema for the RLS objects (predicate function and security policy).

What are the reasons behind this statement? And what is the benefit?

Comment: Schema's are fantastic for _logical_ separation of database objects. For example you might have a bunch of core tables that sit in dbo that take care of your core business functions (manufacturing widgets). Now you go and create a bunch of tables, views and procs that have nothing to do with your core business functions - they only take care of row level security. If you create them in their own seperate schema, they are visually seperated from your other objects in object explorer. Before schemas this may have been achieved by prefixing every object with a special code.

Comment: you might create a schema called `admin` that holds these RLS objects, and any other admin functions such as logging, utility functions, sp_whoisactive etc. or you might create a schema called `rls` that  contains only rls objects. _Use schemas!!!_ - they stop your database becoming a big soup of objects whose functions are not clearly deliniated. Its also a way of making you stop and think about the purpose of objects and where they fit in the big picture

Comment: According to the author of the linked book, "This is because any user should be able to access the functions, and placing the RLS objects in a separate schema makes it easy to manage these permissions".  Link:  https://books.google.fr/books?id=COZODQAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=It+is+highly+recommended+to+create+a+separate+schema+for+the+RLS+objects&source=bl&ots=8Cdr_Ft_Ht&sig=SVga1m681cbyGamqYJmwN1IjJEY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbp6DXh7DTAhUML1AKHZvFCCwQ6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is purely for organization reasons - it is very usefull to have all the security augmentations on one place (under one schema).

Benefits are - your database won't look messy.